# Wordpress Custom Search form with categories and subcategories

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms, search

I have a search form with three fields:

- a checkbox list where we are able to search the categories and child
  categories
- a checkbox list with product tags
- an input search box

I need to be able to display and select parent category on the first field(checkbox) and select child-categories for selected parent category on the second field(also checkbox). The third field should display a list of product tags.

This is the code I have:

```
 <div class="courses-3">    

  <div class="search-box">                           
  <h4> <?php echo $atts['title']?></h4>                            
      <div class="browse-box"> 
      <form name="vedant" method="GET" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" class="form-inline">    
      <?php if($atts['search_cat'] == true) { ?> 
          <div class="form-group">  
          <?php                                        
          if (isset($_REQUEST['product_cat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_cat'])) {                                            
          $optsetlect = $_REQUEST['product_cat']; } 
              else { 
               $optsetlect = 0;                                        }     
                $args = array('show_option_all' => esc_html__('Tecnología', 'vedant'),                  
                    'hierarchical' => parent,
                    'class' => 'cat'
                    'echo' => 1,
                    'value_field' => 'slug',                  
                    'selected' => $optsetlect);              
                   $args['taxonomy'] = 'product_cat';                                        
                   $args['name'] = 'product_cat';                                        
                   wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>                                    
         </div> 

          <div class="form-group form-group-2">                                        

         </div>                                    
         <div class="form-group">                                        
         <span class="or">o</span>                                    
         </div>   
         <?php }                                    
         if($atts['search_search_box'] == true) { ?>                                    

         <div class="form-group">                                        
             <input type="text"  name="s" class="searchbox category-select" value="<?php echo
             get_search_query()?>" placeholder="Buscar...">                                    
         </div>                                    
         <?php } ?>                                    

         <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type">                                    
         <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" title="Browse" class="search-btn-bg b-btn">
                 <span>Explorar</span>
             </button>
      </div>                                
 </form>
```

Comment: You haven't told us what problem you are having or what you need help with.

Comment: I need to create the code so when I select parent categories within the first checkbox the second checkbox auto populates its options with the children categories of the selected category in box one. The third box is independent form the opther two as it{ll work as search box and is already working